# How to create a version formula?

Tags: formula, advanced

I need some help with a version formula. I have 2 types of formula

- `Version_ID` (This number express the id of the `Custom_object__c`)
- `Progression_Version` (This number express the progression of the `Custom_object__c`)

Table created with excel

[image]

Thank you for your attentions,

Comment: Hi @Maronno_mio, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you very much for the tips. (+1)

Comment: @Maronno_mio, your question is still not clear. You may want to clarify it more like is the formula you want is a custom formula field in Salesforce or something else and is the Progression version a field in your custom object?

Comment: I need to create two formulas fields (Version_ID, Progression_Version). 

Version_ID express the id of the record. It doesn't change when I did a modify. 

Progression_Version express the Progression_version number when the record is modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two fields, but neither of them is actually a Salesforce Formula Field.

`Version_ID__c` should simply be an Auto Number field. You can set the Display Format to `{0000}` or similar to just show an incrementing number for each new record you create.

`Progression_Version__c` should be a simple Number field. You can increment this field by one each time the record is editing using either Process Builder (with the "prevent recursion" option turned on) or an Apex trigger.